# Complex numbers on an argand diagram

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Three complex numbers $z_1, z_2$ and $z_3$ all have the same magnitude and are evenly spaced around an argand diagram. Given the complex numbers form the vertices of an equilateral triangle with an area of $12$ square units, find the complex numbers, giving your answer in the form $a+bi$.

Comment: What stops you from rotating the triangle by a small amount and getting different answers?

Comment: I copied the question down exactly as it is on my homework, so all the information needed should be there but I too am confused by this.

Comment: Maybe "evenly spaced" has been vaguely conflated with symmetric about the vertical axis perhaps? Unless each vertex is in terms of the same parameter $\theta$

Comment: If it's homework you should show your attempt.